# Zero Ohm resistor with 3-terminal

Tags: resistors, schematics

[image: CC8531 based headset schematic picture,in detail battery charger part]

There, in a high lighted area, are elements named "3 port, 0402 package, zero ohm resistor". Could anyone tell me what it is and how can I implement it in my design? But it has 2 terminal in the datasheet. Thanks for your help!
(Manufacturer: Koa , Part Number: RK73Z1ETTP )

Answer (score 6):

It's likely that this is 3 pads in a row, with the middle one connected to the IC, and the other ones connected to VBUS and GND. This allows you to take a normal 0402 0 ohm resistor and put it on either the left, or the right, connecting the IC pin to either GND or VBUS (or leaving it floating if you install no resistor).

For example, for ISET2, connecting to VBUS means the USB charge current limit is 500ma, while connecting to GND makes it 100ma, and leaving it open disables USB charging.

This is what it would look like connected to GND (resistor is black and white).
[image]

Comment: Sounds like a nightmare for production control, populate left half vs right half of a designator.

Comment: Nice explanation of how the same circuit board can be assembled differently for different sized batteries.

Comment: Thank you all! good complete explanations.

Comment: @crasic its not really a huge problem if you have good process control. Its definitely very useful in prototypes and small batch, but also in large batches with long pcb fab lead times

Comment: @BeB00 not sure what the advantage is vs two reference designators, where you can still have advantage of one fab. Certainly useful practice, but using a three terminal symbol is a bizarre way to handle it IMO

Comment: It does guarantee the placement, since two footprints on the PCB would require manual alignment. You could do some stuff like making one one have a footprint, but then thats extra complication, so i'm not sure theres a perfect way (except having 4 pads, which is what I have done, except that takes up more room).

Comment: especially bizzarre using the top terminal as the output instead of the middle,

Comment: Could someone suggest a part number of such a cool three terminal resistor?